# Node.js function not running in order. Error: Unhandled stream error in pipe

Tags: node.js, json, synchronization, axios, export-to-csv

I updated the function to create the CSV file but now I'm getting an error:

In upload function
internal/streams/legacy.js:57
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\shiv\WebstormProjects\slackAPIProject\billingData\CSV\1548963844106output.csv'

```
var csvFilePath = '';
var JSONFilePath = '';
function sendBillingData(){
  var message = '';
  axios.get(url, {
    params: {
      token: myToken
    }
  }).then(function (response) {
    message = response.data;

    fields = billingDataFields;
    // saveFiles(message, fields, 'billingData/');
    saveFilesNew(message, fields, 'billingData/');
    var file = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/' + csvFilePath);   // <--make sure this path is correct
    console.log(__dirname + '/' + csvFilePath);
    uploadFile(file);
  })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

The saveFilesNew function is:

```
function saveFilesNew(message, options, folder){
  try {
    const passedData = message;

    var relevantData='';

    if (folder == 'accessLogs/'){
      const loginsJSON = message.logins;
      relevantData = loginsJSON;
      console.log(loginsJSON);
    }
    if(folder == 'billingData/'){
      relevantData = passedData.members;
      const profile = passedData.members[0].profile;
    }

    //Save JSON to the output folder
    var date = Date.now();
    var directoryPath = folder + 'JSON/' + date + "output";
    JSONFilePath = directoryPath + '.json';
    fs.writeFileSync(JSONFilePath, JSON.stringify(message, null, 4), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });

    //parse JSON onto the CSV
    const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({ fields });
    const csv = json2csvParser.parse(relevantData);
    // console.log(csv);

    //function to process the CSV onto the file
    var directoryPath = folder + 'CSV/' + date + "output";
    csvFilePath = directoryPath + '.csv';

    let data = [];
    let columns = {
      real_name: 'real_name',
      display_name: 'display_name',
      email: 'email',
      account_type: 'account_type'
    };

    var id = passedData.members[0].real_name;
    console.log(id);

    console.log("messageLength is" +Object.keys(message.members).length);

    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(message.members).length; i++) {
      console.log("value of i is" + i);
      var display_name = passedData.members[i].profile.display_name;
      var real_name = passedData.members[i].profile.real_name_normalized;
      var email = passedData.members[i].profile.email;
      var account_type = 'undefined';
      console.log("name: " + real_name);

      if(passedData.members[i].is_owner){
        account_type = 'Org Owner';
      }
      else if(passedData.members[i].is_admin){
        account_type = 'Org Admin';
      }
      else if(passedData.members[i].is_bot){
        account_type = 'Bot'
      }
      else account_type = 'User';

      data.push([real_name, display_name, email, account_type]);
    }

    console.log(data);

    stringify(data, { header: true, columns: columns }, (err, output) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      fs.writeFileSync(csvFilePath, output, function(err) {
        console.log(output);
        if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
        console.log('my.csv saved.');
      });
    });

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

The upload file function is:

```
function uploadFile(file){
  console.log("In upload function");
  const form = new FormData();
  form.append('token', botToken);
  form.append('channels', 'testing');
  form.append('file', file);
  axios.post('https://slack.com/api/files.upload', form, {
    headers: form.getHeaders()
  }).then(function (response) {
    var serverMessage = response.data;
    console.log(serverMessage);
  });
}
```

So I think the error is getting caused because node is trying to upload the file before its being created. I feel like this has something to do with the asynchronous nature of Node.js but I fail to comprehend how to rectify the code. Please let me know how to correct this and mention any improvements to the code structure/design too. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't wait for the callback provided to `stringify` to be executed, and it's where you create the file. (Assuming this `stringify` function really does acccept a callback.)

Using callbacks (you can make this cleaner with promises and these neat `async`/`await` controls, but let's just stick to callbacks here), it should be more like:

```
function sendBillingData() {
  ...
  // this callback we'll use to know when the file writing is done, and to get the file path
  saveFilesNew(message, fields, 'billingData/', function(err, csvFilePathArgument) {
    // this we will execute when saveFilesNew calls it, not when saveFilesNew returns, see below
    uploadFile(fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/' + csvFilePathArgument))
  });
}

// let's name this callback... "callback".
function saveFilesNew(message, options, folder, callback) {
  ...
  var csvFilePath = ...; // local variable only instead of your global
  ...
  stringify(data, { header: true, columns: columns }, (err, output) => {
    if (err) throw err; // or return callbcack(err);
    fs.writeFile(csvFilePath , output, function(err) { // NOT writeFileSync, or no callback needed
      console.log(output);
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // callback(err); may be a useful approach for error-handling at a higher level
      }
      console.log('my.csv saved.'); // yes, NOW the CSV is saved, not before this executes! Hence:
      callback(null, csvFilePath); // no error, clean process, pass the file path

    });
  });
  console.log("This line is executed before stringify's callback is called!");
  return; // implicitly, yes, yet still synchronous and that's why your version crashes
}
```

Using callbacks that are called only when the expected events happen (a file is done writing, a buffer/string is done transforming...) allows JS to keep executing code in the meantime. And it does keep executing code, so when you need data from an async code, you need to tell JS you need it done before executing your piece.

Also, since you can pass data when calling back (it's just a function), here I could avoid relying on a global `csvFilePath`. Using higher level variables makes things monolithic, like you could not transfer `saveFilesNew` to a dedicated file where you keep your toolkit of file-related functions.

Finally, if your global process is like:

```
function aDayAtTheOffice() {
  sendBillingData();
  getCoffee();
}
```

then you don't need to wait for the billing data to be processed before starting making coffee. However, if your boss told you that you could NOT get a coffee until the billing data was settled, then your process would look like:

```
function aDayAtTheOffice() {
  sendBillingData(function (err) {
    // if (err)  let's do nothing here: you wanted a coffee anyway, right?
    getCoffee();
  });
}
```

(Note that callbacks having potential error as first arg and data as second arg is a convention, nothing mandatory.)

IMHO you should read about [scope](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/#scope-chain) (the argument `callback` could be accessed at a time where the call to `saveFilesNew` was already done and forgotten!), and about [the asynchronous nature of No... JavaScript](http://altitudelabs.com/blog/what-is-the-javascript-event-loop/). ;) (Sorry, probably not the best links but they contain the meaningful keywords, and then Google is your buddy, your friend, your Big Brother.)